# Im using =RAND.BETWEEN(1,8) and =RANK.EQ in order to get random numbers with out repeating them selves in excel but its repeating any ways

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Cloumn A from A2 to A9 I used  `=RAND.BETWEEN(1,8)`, I had the problem that the random numbers repeated them selves so in Column B I used `=RANK.EQ(A2,$A$2:$A$9,0)` expecting to get numbers that won't repeat themselves, but still getting repeated numbers.

[image]

In the image we can see number 6 repeated.

I tried to create random numbers from 1 to 8 with out repeating them selves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=SORTBY(SEQUENCE(8),RANDARRAY(8))
```

Answer (score 2):

### List of Random Numbers

If you have Excel 2021 or MS365, JvdV has posted the answer.
Otherwise, try the following.

[image]

In `A2` use...

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,8)+(ROW(A2)-ROW(A$2)+1)/100
```

and copy down til `A9`.

In `B2:B9` use the array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)...

```
=MATCH(SMALL(A2:A9,ROW(A2:A9)-ROW(A$2)+1),A2:A9,0)
```

... or in `B2` simply use...

```
=MATCH(SMALL(A$2:A$9,ROW(A2)-ROW(A$2)+1),A$2:A$9,0)
```

... and copy down.

I don't have access to legacy Excel so your feedback is welcome.